# Django filter by the number of rows matching a certain condition in a ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, django-1.11

I need to filter for objects where the number of elements in a ManyToMany relationship matches a condition. Here's some simplified models:

```
Place(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
Person(models.Model):
     type = models.CharField(max_length=1)
     place = models.ManyToManyField(Place, related_name="people")
```

I tried to do this:

```
c = Count(Q(people__type='V'))
p = Places.objects.annotate(v_people=c)
```

But this just makes the `.v_people` attribute count the number of People.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since [django-2.0](/questions/tagged/django-2.0), you can use the `filter=...` parameter of the [**`Count(…)`** function <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Count) for this:

```
Place.objects.annotate(
    v_people=Count('people', filter=Q(people__type='V'))
)
```

So this will assign to `v_people` the number of people with `type='V'` for that specific `Place` object.

An alternative is to `.filter(..)` the relation first:

```
Place.objects.filter(
    Q(people__type='V') | Q(people__isnull=True)
).annotate(
    v_people=Count('people')
)
```

Here we thus filter the relation such that we allow `people` that either have `type='V'`, or with no `people` at all (since it is possible that the `Place` has no `people`. We then count the related model.

This generates a query like:

```
SELECT `place`.*, COUNT(`person_place`.`person_id`) AS `v_people`
FROM `place`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `person_place` ON `place`.`id` = `person_place`.`place_id`
LEFT OUTER JOIN `person` ON `person_place`.`person_id` = `person`.`id`
WHERE `person`.`type` = V OR `person_place`.`person_id` IS NULL
```